# How to convert two Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

What is the best way to convert:

```
["Isolated-1", "SVT_FedPortGroup", "SVT_StoragePortGroup", "VM Network", "test-pg-2002"]
```

and this :

```
["target_Isolated-1", "target_SVT_FedPortGroup", "target_SVT_StoragePortGroup","target_VM Network" ,"target_test-pg-2002"];
```

to:

```
"NetworkMaps": [
    {
        "ENVID": null,
        "SourcePG": "Isolated-1",
        "TargetPG": "target_Isolated-1"
    },
    {
        "ENVID": null,
        "SourcePG": "VM Network",
        "TargetPG": "target_SVT_FedPortGroup"
    }...
]
```

I need to to merge two array with respective values.
For example

```
 arr1 : ["a", "b", "c"]; 
 arr2 : ["apple", "ball", "cat"];

result : [{source: "a",target: "apple"}, {source: "b",target: "ball"},{source: "c",target: "cat"}]
```

Comment: provide your efforts what you have tried so far ?

Comment: There are lot of resource to do this.. Please google it..

Comment: Why is `VM Network` is the same group with `target_SVT_FedPortGroup`? And what you have done so far?

Comment: @Eddie VM Network is the same group with target_SVT_FedPortGroup, because of key value. [3] -> [3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just map them per index (if they have the same length) in a simple loop. Here is a demo:

```js
a = ["Isolated-1", "SVT_FedPortGroup", "SVT_StoragePortGroup", "VM Network", "test-pg-2002"]
b = ["target_Isolated-1", "target_SVT_FedPortGroup", "target_SVT_StoragePortGroup", "target_VM Network", "target_test-pg-2002"]
c = {
  "NetworkMaps": []
}
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  c.NetworkMaps.push({
    "ENVID": null,
    "SourcePG": a[i],
    "TargetPG": b[i]
  })
}
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Thanks Aleksey Solovey. The length are always same. but Is it possible to merge them with key value? ex: arr1.[0] and arr2[0] , arr1.[1] and arr2[1] ..etc?

Comment: @JeetPatel that looks like a wrong syntax (`arr1.[0]`). You can also map them without an array with `c.NetworkMaps = a.map((e,i) => {return {"ENVID":null, "SourcePG":e, "TargetPG":b[i]}})`

Comment: its working for me. But i think i should handle it in different way. Thanks again Aleksey Solovey.

Comment: @JeetPatel try asking questions with a description of your **problem** and not [attempted **solution**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)